# Can Cloud9's ACE editor handle something like flyspell spell checking?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I checked on-line and Wikipedia reports that ACE does spell checking, as part of some context menu add-on-- but I can't find same in the Cloud9 environment.

Comment: Did you ever get this working, if so what did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Ace doesn't have built-in spellchecker but there are several sites using Ace that support spellcheking ([zed](http://zedapp.org/), [papeeria](http://papeeria.com), [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/)).
 So in short ace can handle spellchecking but it is not enabled in cloud9.